# How to protect my belongings at the beach

Tags: safety, summer

Summer is coming up and it's beach weather. So whenever I go to the beach, I'm always conscious that someone might want to try and steal my stuff.

**So what would be the best way to protect/hide my valuables like my**:

- Phone
- Money
- Car Keys

Note: I'd rather not put it in my bag as I've had various experiences where people have taken mine/my friends bags and just walked off, ending up in me loosing all of my personal belongings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Some ways are:**

- Put it in a fannypack, this way it is always with you. You can even swim with if you put the phone in a plastic bag. Clear Plastic bags make it so you that you can still use the phone in the bag.
- Use a empty clip on water bottle. This water bottle can connect to your clothes and is waterproof.
- Wear your possesions. Lanyards for your keys, ankle or wrist pouches for your money and clip on cases for your phone. I usually opt for a case that slides in a belt loop and clips on for added protection.

**Other methods that are common on the internet:**

- Put the stuff in a diaper and ball it up. People may think it is dirty. If you are feeling mean you can even color it brown and fill it with brown clay. They may throw it away it they are a do-gooder so watch it closely.

[image]

- Put the stuff in a container that no one will suspect. Like ice cream cartons, milk cartons, deodorant jars, etc. Deodarant cartons can even fit in your pocket.

[Picture Link](http://www.diyncrafts.com/7569/lifehacks/20-genius-summer-lifehacks-will-blow-mind/2).

Comment: There are waterproof cell phone cases with lanyards for less than US$10, handy for canoeing, kayaking and other water sports, as well as swimming.

Comment: "They may throw it away it they are a do-gooder so watch it closely."  Doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose ? If you're going to "watch it closely", I doubt you need do anything in addition to this ;)  lol  (heh .. dirty diapers .. cute .. )

Comment: @Ditto Putting the diaper in a purse would hide it from everyone but thieves. This is probably better as a solution.

Comment: Anything that disguises your valuables as garbage is a really terrible idea. Instead of being vulnerable to thieves, your valuables are now vulnerable to well-meaning members of the public *and* the people the municipality pays to pick up garbage in public places. Disguising your valuables as disgusting garbage (a used diaper) is antisocial as well as self-defeating.

Answer (score 4):

Stuff them into your shoes when you take your shoes off. Put them in first, then your socks so it looks like only your socks are sticking out. If you are wearing sandals, might be worth it to bring an extra ratty pair of shoes to stuff into. Very common sight at the beach, but no one will steal an old pair of shoes.

Answer (score 3):

Some companies now sell lockable box that clamps onto your beach chair or the handle of your ice chest.  One brand is [AquaVault](https://theaquavault.com/); there are probably others.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Definitively not fool-proof, but if you are at a beach with sand, you could bury the stuff in the sand under your blanket or similar. When it is out of sight, it is not that easy to steal, and then the burglar actually have to see you bury it and they have to dig it out of the sand.

In general I would usually go for carrying the most valuable stuff on me. Or possibly hide it away in the car, and carry only the car key.